# Basic Authentication of Rest API's

Tags: java, spring

I have some api's created using springboot.Now i want to keep authentication for rest api's. Only particular user can access his data.
I have two tables in  postgress database listed below.

[image]

1.Hitting api without header,works fine with proper response code

[image]

2.Hitting api with basic auth where userid and password should match with db
[image]

[image]

My expectation is proper json response with status code 200,but still it is coming 401 Unauthorized.Why?

**My SecurityConfig.java file**

```
package com.demo.itemservice.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

     @Autowired
     private DataSource dataSource;



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .httpBasic();


    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
          .usersByUsernameQuery("select userid,pgp_sym_decrypt(password,'mySecretKey') from users where userid=?")
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select userid, role from userroles where userid=?");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your password column of type text or bytea?

Comment: password is of type bytea

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the following code ? I replaced **anyRequest()** with **antMatchers()**.

```
 http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/barista/**").authenticated()
         .and()
         .httpBasic();
```

Comment: Replaced and checked,getting 401  unauthorized

Comment: Ok, can you check now the password whether is it decrypting properly ?

Comment: to validate userid and password from postgres database ,we should use auth.jdbcAuthentication() (or)  auth.authenticationProvider ?

Comment: Can you check this link, https://www.boraji.com/spring-security-5-jdbc-based-authentication-example

Comment: You can check this link. https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-boot-security-database-authentication-example/

Answer (score 0):

Decrypting bytea data with pgp_sym_decrypt is disallowed. This is to avoid outputting invalid character data. Decrypting originally textual data with pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea is fine.
Ref [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/pgcrypto.html)